# How to handle a Variable containg a NULL / None Value in grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

Then issue is on (live time) variable define in Grafana is not containing the value, in that case my Grafana panel is throwing and error with empty brackets
e.g. Error :- case when id IN () then 0 else 1

Error Message:-  Error: The 'id' variable is empty, causing the query to fail. Please ensure the 'id' variable is properly configured and contains valid values.

I tried with Mysql COALESCE() and  IFNULL() Function to overcome this issue , but it didnt help me .